# Transform scale of container and invert transform scale of child

Tags: css, transform, scale, transition, easing

I have a problem with scaling in CSS. `div.container` has `transform: scale(0.1)`, so because of normal font size, `h1` in this element has `transform: scale(10)`.

After hover, `div.container` has `transform: scale(0.5)` and `h1` `transform: scale(2)`. Everything is animated (`transition: all 1s ease-in-out`).

However, animation of `h1` isn't as fast as animation of `div.container`, so after hover, `h1` is very big at the beginning of animation, and then quicky shrinks.

I think it's happening because of `h1` should have invert easing. But what easing is invert to `ease-in-out`? Or is the problem elsewhere?

**Note:** I can't scaling only `div.image`. This code is only example. I have to scaling `div.container`.

```css
.container, .title {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
}

.container {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  transform: scale(10);
}

.container:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.container:hover .title {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image">
   
   </div>
   <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it doesn't work with linear easing. So, problem is not in easing.

```css
.container, .title {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
}

.container {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  transform: scale(10);
}

.container:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.container:hover .title {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image">
   
   </div>
   <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```